# Postgres error while running SELECT Query

Tags: sql, postgresql

When running select query i am getting below error. I am new to postgres and need your suggestions on this.

```
ERROR: could not seek to end of segment 0 of relation pg_table1/23111/191232/112333: Input/output error
```

Please suggest what could be the reasons.

Comment: More details would be appreciated... Table structure, request...

Comment: What version of Postgres are you running? Please post full logs if possible.

Comment: I dont have much information about table str, etc. Postgres version is 8.4.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messages like that are typically signs of some kind of corruption.  This link touches on some similar things.  [Stark Presentation](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3ahoA62_C6JzMJ%3awww.postgresql.jp/events/pgcon09j/doc/A2-2.pdf%20postgres%20could%20not%20seek%20to%20end%20of%20segment%200%20of%20relation&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESjgiCBUd_DL7ZnmnPxtBn403D4YJ39qvB_38-0H5hvog22kRLyjmuwU55VmWL-WKJSCV7paE-gnMf8W4wG497C_SFRiiPuEp8L81fxPi92yvw9VjZcLjDfKN30omENVe0_vxeD1&sig=AHIEtbQaU2_UK4pYZrgAO_2UMx2utXry2A)

Comment: Yes, the requests for more information are missing the point. You have corrupt database files due to one of:
 1. disk errors
 2. operating-system / vm bugs
 3. crashes while disks weren't respecting fsync or similar

The thing to do is shut down postgresql, take a backup of all the files (including WAL) and see what you can recover. If you have a recent backup, just restore from that - it'll be quicker.

Then, find out what's broken on your system - it's unlikely to be PostgreSQL corrupting your data unless you've been hacking on it yourself.